# react-dropzone The files parameter in onDrop = (files) returning null

Tags: react-dropzone

```
import {Component} from 'react';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';

import style from './LogUploader.css';

export class LogUploader extends Component {
    state = {
        message: t('logreader', 'Load log file')
    };

    isLog (content) {
        return content[0] === '{' && content[content.length - 1] === '}';
    }

    onDrop = (files) => {
        const file = files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e) => {
            const content = e.target.result.trim();
            if (!this.isLog(content)) {
                this.setState({message: t('logreader', 'Invalid log file')});
                return;
            }
            this.props.onLogFile(content);
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    };

    render () {
        const dropStyle = {
            display: 'inline-block',
            margin: '5px'
        };

        return (
            <Dropzone multiple={false} accept="text/*" className={"button"} style={dropStyle}
                      onDrop={this.onDrop}>
                {({getRootProps, getInputProps}) => <button {...getRootProps()}>{this.state.message}<input {...getInputProps()}/></button>}
            </Dropzone>
        );
    }
}
```

[debug info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPKgN.png)

As shown in the above code, after selecting the upload file, the files parameter in onDrop = (files) always returns a null value. Is there anything wrong with the code above? Thanks!

Comment: give only important snippets not the complete code

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate with `useDropzone()` instead of importing `*` from the library. This will give you more control over customization.

```
// handler function
const onDrop = (files) => {
    // files is an array of all uploaded files
    console.info("accepted file!!", files[0]);
};


// at the top-level in your component
const { getRootProps, getInputProps } = useDropzone({
    onDropAccepted: onDrop, // your handler function
    multiple: false,
    accept: {
        "image/png": [".png"]
    }
});

return () {
    <div>
        <button {...getRootProps({ className: "myDropZoneButton" })}>
            upload
        </button>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
    </div>
}
```

Here's a [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dropzone-udrn8l?file=/src/App.js:102-231) using functional component.